# How to prevent an idea / innovation from being stolen or plagiarised

Tags: publications, plagiarism, independent-researcher

I have come up with an innovation to obtain linear motion without using any external source of energy. The idea arose from a paper I wrote on an alternative model of magnetism. I have built and tested the innovation and have written a paper describing it, which I wish to submit for publication.

My worry is that considering the novelty of the idea, it may get stolen or plagiarized. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Don't worry about it, every physicist and engineer has already run into thousands of people _exactly_ like you. You all have so many ways to get free energy that we couldn't keep up with stealing them if we wanted to.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about free energy so I don't see how you have jumped to that conclusion. You also seem to assume for some reason that i am not a physicist or an engineer. Thanks for your advice about not worrying.

Comment: @VH.Ryan knzhou is being sarcastic

Comment: @VH.Ryan if there is no external source of energy, in what sense is the energy not “free”?

Comment: Publish it. This will establish primacy.

Comment: @knzhou, Dan Romik - please don't...

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "stolen or plagiarized"?  Are you afraid you won't get credit in the history books?  That someone else will commercialize it and you won't get anything?  It would help if we knew specifically what it is that you don't want to happen.

Comment: Dan Romik, I don't claim to have invented a device that produces usable energy without putting any energy into it.  Magnetic and gravitational fields exert force which lead to motion.

Comment: David Thornley, what I mean by stolen and plagiarized is the same that it means to other authors,  that some one will claim my work to be theirs. I don't seem to be the only one to have this concern. The device in its present form has little commercial value, but the idea behind it is certainly novel.

Comment: @VH.Ryan thanks for the clarification. There’s still the tricky issue of the second law of thermodynamics that would eventually cause the motion to cease unless external energy is provided to the system, but I assume you are aware of that. In any case, good luck with your invention.

Comment: Dan Romik This is not a perpetual motion device. The issue with magnet motors is the need to overcome the "neutral position" ie the point where the attractive and repulsive forces cancel each other. Is it possible to obtain a linear force with no "attraction" or "repulsion" involved? Apparently it is possible.

Comment: @VH.Ryan I understand. I deleted my earlier comment making reference to perpetual motion devices. Obviously devices that involve motion that is not perpetual are perfectly possible, and no doubt there is room for innovation in the world of such devices. As I said, good luck with the invention.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an invention, patent it. It's an expensive and long process though. But it may be dangerous to publish the paper first. Your patent could possibly be denied if the paper is deemed "prior art". This varies by jurisdiction, of course. Keep it as a trade secret until you file the patent.

You can't actually "prevent" plagiarism. You can only try to reveal it.

If you publish the paper without obtaining patent on the "invention", then people are free to use the idea. They just can't legally violate your copyright nor morally plagiarize the paper. But, ideas are free to use.

If the idea is valid and novel, you might be able to partner with some company to exploit it. Don't reveal it, however, without non-disclosure agreements in place first.

Much of this requires a lawyer, of course.

Comment: Inventions are only worth patenting if they have potential for significant commercial value.

Comment: You can apply for a patent *after* publishing at an academic conference in some countries. (So, it isn't generally true that "If you publish the paper without obtaining patent on the "invention", then people are free to use the idea.") That said, I'd strongly recommend filing a patent first.

Comment: @user2768. True enough in general. It is an expensive process. A partner can help and then the game changes a bit. Patents can be filed just to prevent competitors from following up on certain lines. A friend "has" a patent on a tiny-tiny idea that made for a strategic advantage for a large company.

Comment: Indeed, large companies certainly have more options (regarding patents) than individuals!

Comment: _But don’t publish the paper first. Your patent will then be denied._ That’s not true - see [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/can-i-file-a-patent-after-publishing-as-part-of-collaborative-public-content) or google “patent grace period”. You really shouldn’t be offering legal advice about things that are not within your expertise. This may not matter in OP’s situation but other people may read what you wrote and be misled.

Comment: If this is, as it seems from the description, an example of a "perpetual motion machine", then it is going to be very difficult if not impossible to patent it in most countries; patent offices typically refuse to allow these, since they are invariably delusions or illusions. [Reference - Europe](https://academic.oup.com/jiplp/article/2/3/136/2358262), [Australia](https://blog.patentology.com.au/2015/04/patenting-perpetual-motion.html), [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Patents)

Comment: @DanRomik. I was giving the most conservative advice I could. As reported elsewhere on this site, in some places a prior publication by a patent filer can be taken as disqualifying prior art. Better to be safe than find out later.

Comment: My complaint is that you were giving factually incorrect advice. How conservative it is, or whether there is some element of truth or wisdom in it, is irrelevant to that particular issue.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and responses. I don't see why "free energy and :"perpetual motion machines" have been introduced into this discussion when I haven't made any reference to these at all.  The paper I wrote seemed to indicate that a constant linear force could be obtained using permanent magnets and the device constructed was to test this theory. This linear force is not an attractive or repulsive force.This is neither free energy nor perpetual motion.

Comment: @Buffy, I did think of filing for a provisional patent, but the device as of now has little commercial value and as you mentioned the process is tedious. However the idea behind the device is novel and that is what my concern is

Comment: @VH.Ryan, if you make the idea public it may not be patentable by others (prior art), but that isn't the same as not being able to be exploited by others. Remember that copyright doesn't help you here. It only protects your words, not your ideas.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a truly new idea, it's very unlikely anyone will want to steal it.  You will have to sell it, first.  Think of [Steve Ballmer's reaction to the iPhone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eywi0h_Y5_U).

But to take your question a bit more seriously, you have basically four strategies for protecting your intellectual property:

1. Trade secret.  You license your IP to licensees who promise to keep
   it secret as well.  Your protection is that your IP is so clever
   that you don't think it's likely anyone can independently recreate
   it without knowing how you did it.  Works surprisingly well (think
   formula for Coca-Cola).  But if your idea is recreated, there's
   nothing you can do about it, especially if they decide to patent
   before you do.
2. Patent.  This applies to inventions, like what you're describing. 
   You publish your idea by submitting it to the patent authority in
   your country.  If your patent is granted, you can prohibit others
   from using your idea without licensing it.  But it's expensive, both
   to get the patent and to enforce it and whether you got the patent
   or not, everyone can read your idea.
3. Copyright.  This applies primarily to written, audio or video
   material and would include, e.g., any computer source code in your
   product.  Copyrights exist from the moment of conception, though if you
   want to sue someone for copyright infringement you must first
   register your copyright (very cheap).
4. You can give it away.  You can publish it with, e.g., a GNU or
   similar open source license.  This lets anyone use your IP but that
   also ensures you can always use it as well.

Comment: Or Woz and the idea of a desktop computer. But those ideas were so far outside the consciousness of the listener that they were dismissed as ridiculous.

Comment: In its present form the device has little commercial value, my concern is of someone claiming my work to be their own especially since it is "a truly new idea"  as the OP in this question has experienced :https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100071/a-reviewer-has-stolen-my-idea-what-can-i-do?rq=1

Comment: @Buffy Yes, unlike a linear motion machine with no external power source, which no one has any problem with.

Comment: I have no idea what his machine is. He speaks of magnetism, That could imply using the Earth's magnetic field as a "power source". I withheld judgement, not knowing more.

Comment: Perhaps one should ask: What's OP's priority? Business value? Or recognition? In the first case, options 1 and 2 (and to a lesser extent 3) apply. In the latter case, options 3 and 4 apply (or 5, a publication).